# Why does Git detect rename without --find-renames?

Tags: git

[image]

I run `git log --name-status -1` and Git detects a renaming. From what I read on https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log, renaming detection is only enabled when --find-renames is specified. Why does Git detect rename without `--find-renames`?

If renaming detection is enabled out of box, it's great. I believe Tests/ProgramTest.cs => Tests/StringExtensionsTest.cs is also a rename. How do I ask Git to calculate similarity index and show it as rename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git will detect renames if directed.  This direction is under various control knobs; one of these is the `diff.renames` setting.  The default value for `diff.renames` is `false` in Git versions predating Git 2.9, and [`true` in Git versions from 2.9 onward](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt).

(Note that command line flags override `diff.renames`, so you can explicitly turn rename detection *off* if you want.  Note also that "plumbing" commands like `git diff-tree` generally do not read user configuration settings such as `diff.renames` and `diff.renameLimit` so that script behavior will be predictable, rather than depending on the user's configuration settings.)

Comment: Is the default similarity threshold 50%? Can I change that? Can I ask Git to calculate similarity index of Tests/ProgramTest.cs => Tests/StringExtensionsTest.cs ?

Comment: (1) yes, it's 50%; (2) not with a configuration entry, only with the command line flag; and (3) not directly. Git does its similarity test only on "unpaired" files (loosely defined as a file whose path *P* in the source tree has no matching *P* in the destination tree, or vice versa) or files whose pairings were temporarily broken via a `-B` argument if any. Git then pairs the "most similar" file pair as long as it exceeds the threshold, and only then shows you the diff and the similarity index number.